# How would I go about storing an array of all occurences of missed calls per store per day?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm making a script that will store a date, the store name, and then a list of times that we missed calls for that store during that day. I wish to write this information to a document sometime in the future. I read in a csv using pandas to create the DataFrame.

My DataFrame looks like:

```
Date                            Store          Time
9/3/2023             Location A (8005)         8:29:29 AM
9/3/2023             Location B (8004)         9:03:58 AM
9/3/2023             Location B (8004)         9:45:45 AM
9/3/2023             Location C (8003)         9:50:29 AM
9/3/2023             Location D (8006)         9:51:35 AM
...                     ...                       ...
9/9/2023             Location B (8004)         8:31:50 PM
9/9/2023             Location D (8006)        10:34:26 PM
9/9/2023             Location D (8006)        10:39:53 PM
9/9/2023             Location C (8003)        11:48:46 PM
9/9/2023             Location C (8003)        11:50:33 PM
```

I think the optimal format would be something like:

```
{'9/03/23' : {'Location A' : [list of times],...,'Location D' : [list of times]},...,'9/09/23' : ...}
```

Here's the function that I came up with:

```
def calls_perDay_perStore(df):
    d = defaultdict(dict)
    arr = []
    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        d[row.Date][row.Store] = arr
        d[row.Date][row.Store].append(row.Time)
    dict(d)
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'9/3/2023': {'Location A (8005)': [' 8:29:29 AM', ' 9:03:58 AM'...],...,{'Location D (8006}'}...'9/9/2023': {...}}
```

This code just appended all of the times in the DataFrame into the array. I would assume I'd need to check if the key is the same name as the row.Store name before appending. Any help would be appreciated. Also, sorry about the formatting issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
out = {}
for (date, store), g in df.groupby(['Date', 'Store']):
    out.setdefault(date, {})[store] = g['Time'].tolist()
```

Or in pure pandas (maybe less efficient):

```
out = (df.groupby('Date')
         .apply(lambda g: g.groupby('Store')['Time'].agg(list).to_dict())
         .to_dict()
      )
```

Output:

```
{'9/3/2023': {'Location A (8005)': ['8:29:29 AM'],
              'Location B (8004)': ['9:03:58 AM', '9:45:45 AM'],
              'Location C (8003)': ['9:50:29 AM'],
              'Location D (8006)': ['9:51:35 AM']},
 '9/9/2023': {'Location B (8004)': ['8:31:50 PM'],
              'Location C (8003)': ['11:48:46 PM', '11:50:33 PM'],
              'Location D (8006)': ['10:34:26 PM', '10:39:53 PM']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to format your `Date` and `Store` columns:

```
df["StoreExport"] = df["Store"].apply(lambda x: x.split(" (")[0])
df["DateExport"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%#m/%d/%y")
```

Then group on these columns to get call times (@mozway solution is more elegant for this step):

```
calls = df.groupby(["DateExport","StoreExport"])["Time"].apply(list)
calls_dict = {level: calls.xs(level).to_dict() for level in calls.index.levels[0]}
```

Which results in:

```
print(call_dict)

{'9/03/23': {'Location A': ['8:29:29 AM'],
             'Location B': ['9:03:58 AM', '9:45:45 AM'],
             'Location C': ['9:50:29 AM'],
             'Location D': ['9:51:35 AM']},
 '9/09/23': {'Location B': ['8:31:50 PM'],
             'Location C': ['11:48:46 PM', '11:50:33 PM'],
             'Location D': ['10:34:26 PM', '10:39:53 PM']}}
```